# Which is recommended for speed, dynamic desaturation or double images?

Tags: jquery

I would love to hear performance recommendation regarding image desaturation. I want to have an animation from desaturated to saturated image, and vice versa. So far I manage to use a jquery plugin to animate them on the fly. But just wonder about the performance implication with hundred of thumbnails on a page. Which do you recommend for better speed? Jquery or two static images with simpler animation?

UPDATE: FYI, apart from 20 preloaded images, the rest are loaded via ajax like google infinite scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the animation is simply from desaturated to saturated, or vice-versa, layer one over the other and animate the opacity causing the top to fade in or out. The transition will be the same, if not better, with only 2 images needed, not 20.

Comment: Transition is both ways. 20 images are referred to the first loaded images on the first page render. Another 20 is loaded at window scroll, and so on. Using desaturation plugin, the top is desaturated canvas, and below is the actual color image. I wonder about performance difference between both approaches. Thanks

Comment: I finaly went with 2 images, and indeed faster rather than canvas or svg. Thanks